# Dynamic Fields On A Serializer For A ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I set up a serializer that is able to dynamically serialize the desired fields as specified in the Django Rest Framework docs.

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)
```

```
>>> class UserSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
>>>     class Meta:
>>>         model = User
>>>         fields = ['id', 'username', 'email']
>>>
>>> print(UserSerializer(user))
{'id': 2, 'username': 'jonwatts', 'email': 'jon@example.com'}
>>>
>>> print(UserSerializer(user, fields=('id', 'email')))
{'id': 2, 'email': 'jon@example.com'}
```

How would I then add in a model that is related by ForeignKey to this and dynamically serialize the desired fields from that model?

We could make the models

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = IntegerField()
    username = CharField()
    email = EmailField()

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    color = CharField()
    type = CharField
    year = DateField()
    driver = ForeignKey(User)
```

and then based on the view either include color, type, year, or any combination of those.

I would like something like this.

```
{
  'id': 27,
  'username': 'testuser',
  'vehicle: {
     'color': 'Blue',
     'type': 'Truck',
  }
}
```

Comment: One approach is to override `ModelSerializer`'s `build_nested_field`, but you will have to find a way for this method to know which field you want to customise, and the fields you want to dynamically set for that field's nested serializer. Maybe using `context`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a nested dict you could simply do

```
class VehicleSeralizer(serialzers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Vehicle
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(seralizers.ModelSerializer):
    vehicle = VehicleSerializer()
    class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ['id', 'username', 'email'] # you might need to add 'vehicle'
```

Comment: I think OP is asking how to dynamically set `VehicleSeralizer`'s fields but through `UserSerializer`

Comment: Yes, I would like to dynamically determine which fields the VehicleSerializer will serialize as well.  So something like UserSerializer(user, fields=('id', 'email'), secondary_fields=('color')